# Problem with install ROS indigo on Jetson TX1 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem with this question:
[http://answers.ros.org/question/196194/...](http://answers.ros.org/question/196194/ros-indigo-installation-for-ubuntu-arm-jetson-tk1-ubuntu-1404/)
I followed the answer in that question but it doesn't work. I have all three universe, restricted, and multiverse selected.
I post again the problem when install Indigo here:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-ros-base : Depends: ros-indigo-actionlib but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-bond-core but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-class-loader but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-dynamic-reconfigure but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-nodelet-core but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-pluginlib but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-ros-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit 1: I tried to install from source http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source, but it failed at the first step

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

Thank you very much for reading and answering my question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229562/problem-with-install-ros-indigo-on-jetson-tx1-ubuntu-14.04/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

build-essential is a core package in Ubuntu; not being able to install it is surprising

Are you really running Ubuntu, or are you running a custom Nvidia OS image that is based on Ubuntu?

Do you have the Ubuntu main, restricted, universe and multiverse repositories enabled in your apt sources?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-03-22**:
@ahendrix: I enabled main which I didn't enable before since I follow the instruction and it is installing now. And I install ros-indigo-desktop. I will update you after install completed.
I have ROS installed success now. Thank you for your help.